# Why is so difficult to detect polymorphic malware?

Tags: detection, malware

Why is so difficult to detect polymorphic malware?

Is not enough build a signature after decompress the encrypted part of the malware?

And then match this signature with another possible version of the malware simply by doing a similar process?

With similar process I mean decompress on real time the encrypted part of the malware using software like PEID, and then test against signatures previously generated.

With signature, I am doing reference to the classic signature used in antivirus software, a sintactic signature (regular expresion of hexadecimals for example).

**EDIT:**

Why don't consider malware all software that can't be correctly unpacked?

Benign software also use custom pack methods?

**EDIT:**

¿How do you know if a software is packed?
¿If the software is packed you always can be aware of that?
¿Can you always know where is the beginning of the obfuscated part of the malware?

¿What about mimimorphism?

Is there some book or handbook specific about polymorphic malware?
Or about obfuscated malware?
I appreciate any reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no it's not that simple. 
First of all, PEiD detects the packer used to pack the sample by signature. So you are assuming the packer has a constant signature, which is not polymorphism. Polymorphism is simply a method to obfuscate (encrypt, pack or encode) the file where the deobfuscation part (decryptor) of the file is constantly changing on every infection, so no static signature can be extracted from it for PEiD. A more generalized idea is Metamorphism, where not just the decryptor changes, but the entire code, then no need to encrypt/decrypt since all the file is not constant .. but those are VERY hard to write.

Another challenge is when you decide to automatically stop the decompression process. This is an open problem until now. There are some heuristics to detect the end of decryption, but those can work only with weak obfuscation methods.

Comment: I had understood that there are softwares capable of unpack the majority of the polymorphic malware, present on the wild. I am wrong?

Even, I had read papers where the authors use softwares like peid or other (maybe peid no, I don't remember well) to unpack malware and then do some analysis, for example opcode distribution, or control flow graph, etc.

What I don't understand is, If they can unpack the malware, why not only use a hexadecimal signature?

Or I have some mistake?

Comment: PEiD is not used for unpacking, it's used to detect which packer has packed the file. It uses signature databases of some packer and search for this signature in the file.
There are however some automated unpacking tools to unpack popular packers, such as UPX, FSB, Themida, etc. But those are for a few popular off-the-shelf packers. For custom packing, which is specific to a  malware, there are unguaranteed heuristic techniques as I said earlier.

If you can refer me to one of these papers that claim automatic polymorphic unpacking, maybe I can give you a better answer.

Comment: For example, in the paper "A graph mining approach for detecting unknown malwares" in the section: "3.2. Constructing API-CFG", they use PE Explorer, with UPX Unpacker plug-in to unpack  packed malware.

I had read other paper (I am looking for this paper right now) where the authors use some unpacker and can unpack the majority of the malwares that  they analyse.

Comment: And in the paper "A framework for metamorphic malware analysis and real-time detection" the authors say this:

"In the current version of MARD, the component Unpacker is not implemented, and we assume that all the samples are unpacked before they are disassembled. We have taken this assumption in a view that if a program cannot be unpacked by the current available unpackers then the program is a malware, and also any good available unpacker can be interfaced with MARD."

Comment: The first paper you mentioned, uses unpacker for UPX. UPX is one of the **easiest** packers out there. It is _not_ polymorphic.
Regarding real-time decompression, yes it can be done for public packers that we know their techniques, so we reverse the algorithm in the unpacker. However, for custom packers, a heuristic universal unpacker is used, but those are unreliable as I mentioned before.
Last thing, the assumption of _"if a program cannot be unpacked by a current available unpacker, then it's a malware"_ is definitely wrong and unscientific. What can stop a benign program be custom packed?!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answer, in order for a syntactic signature to work you need to have some reliable mechanism for getting the full unpacked binary. However, packers that implement incremental unpacking (such as Themida and (I think) Armadillo) make this difficult. Some of these incremental packers create packed executables where the original instructions are packed/unpacked on the local function or basic block level, that is, during execution 'just in time' unpacking is performed on a local function body or basic block right before the function or block is executed. After execution the function or block may be repacked to make sure that the entire unpacked executable is never in memory.

If the signature matches instructions across functions or basic blocks it will never match since there is never a case where the fully unpacked program appears in memory.

> Why don't consider malware all software that can't be correctly unpacked?

It looks like existing AV scanners can configured to do something like this, specifically flag ANYTHING packed as malicious. At work I was playing with several standard packers (UPX and Packman) and the AV scanner would trigger and delete all of the packed (benign) executables I created. I wound up running the packers under Wine in Linux to avoid Windows AV.

> Are any benign programs packed?

Maybe. I've only seen 1 benign program that was packed (software that came with a Toshiba external USB drive I bought was packed with UPX for some reason). It is possible that some benign software is packed with a protector to make reverse engineering harder.